# vlc - audio stuttering on certain dvds only - Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, vlc, spdif

This PC has been on Ubuntu for ~10 years. It has never been plain sailing but had been working until 2 days ago when we left a DVD video on pause in VLC. When we unpaused a few hours later, the audio started stuttering constantly at high volume that can't be lowered in either VLC or the OS once it starts.

The DVD video/image playback looks ok.
Playback of .mp4 files in VLC is okay (so a potential workround is to rip the DVDs).
Audio works fine in Firefox, Steam games etc - so I believe the problem is isolated to vlc dvd playback.

The dvds it has happened to so far reputedly have some copy protection or encryption on them. I suppose scrambling the sound might be a feature of that.

The soundcard is onboard: HDA Intel
Playback is IEC958 / SPDIF digital stereo, which goes to an AV Receiver, which is currently set to split the stereo signal into virtual 5.1 surround sound.
If I buy an adaptor there would exist the option to play sound via the graphics card and use HDMI instead.

The audio is set to Pulseaudio Sound Server. Switching it to ALSA doesn't seem to affect this problem.

vlc is giving numerous error messages (pasted below), most of which I've searched and the results haven't seemed particularly useful so far.

At the moment I think it might be a problem with the buffer size or that too many other programs are open relative to the buffer. So I'm looking at vlc Advanced Preferences > Input/Codecs. But if anyone has seen the same errors I'd be hugely grateful for any pointers.

This block of errors reflects multiple attempts

````
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[000055f012e10580] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[000055f012eb03d0] main playlist: playlist is empty
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 4434, resource id: 23207761, major code: 40 (TranslateCoords), minor code: 0
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: DVD Title: HOBBIT_BATTLE_OF_FIVE_ARMIES
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: DVD Serial Number: 46435A1D
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: DVD Title (Alternative): HOBBIT_BATTLE_OF_FIVE_ARMIES
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00e50000. Regions: 02 04 05
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007fe344004fc0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007fe344004fc0] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[00007fe344004fc0] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[00007fe344004fc0] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
[00007fe344004fc0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  510.108.03  Thu Oct 20 04:59:03 UTC 2022 for hardware decoding
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[000055f012ee0e70] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007fe35c1b4c30] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00007fe35c1b4c30] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed for 128389: no reference clock
[00007fe35c1b4c30] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 0 for spdif
[000055f012ee0e70] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007fe35c1c69c0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00007fe344004fc0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007fe344004fc0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  510.108.03  Thu Oct 20 04:59:03 UTC 2022 for hardware decoding
[00007fe3500015b0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 1000 ms)
[00007fe3500015b0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (jitter of 35228 ms ignored)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 3361, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100050639013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 3361, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100050679013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 12825, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100050719013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 12825, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100050759013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 13130, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100050799013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 13130, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100050839013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 13130, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100050879013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 20749, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100050919013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 20749, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100050959013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 20749, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100050999013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 20749, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100051039013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 20749, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100051079013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 20749, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100051119013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 20749, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100051159013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 20749, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100051199013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 20749, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100051239013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 20749, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100051279013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 20749, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100051319013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 20749, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100051359013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 20749, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100051399013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 20749, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100051439013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 20749, bound 9000000)
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 100051479013 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed for 10438012: no reference clock
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not get display date for timestamp 0
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed for 10438012: no reference clock
[00007fe35c06bbe0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 0 for FFmpeg
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007fe344004fc0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007fe344004fc0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007fe35c1b4c30] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  510.108.03  Thu Oct 20 04:59:03 UTC 2022 for hardware decoding
[00007fe35c1b4c30] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007fe3500015b0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (jitter of 35228 ms ignored)
[00007fe35c0042c0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007fe35c1b4c30] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[000055f012ee0e70] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007fe35c1b4c30] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[000055f012ee0e70] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007fe35c1b4c30] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[000055f012ee0e70] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007fe35c1b4c30] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00007fe344004fc0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007fe344004fc0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007fe35c1c69c0] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  510.108.03  Thu Oct 20 04:59:03 UTC 2022 for hardware decoding
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
dave@ubuntustudio2019:~$ vlc
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[0000564ce1080580] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0000564ce11203d0] main playlist: playlist is empty
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: DVD Title: HOBBIT_BATTLE_OF_FIVE_ARMIES
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: DVD Serial Number: 46435A1D
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: DVD Title (Alternative): HOBBIT_BATTLE_OF_FIVE_ARMIES
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00e50000. Regions: 02 04 05
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f94740048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f94740048b0] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[00007f94740048b0] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[00007f94740048b0] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
[00007f94740048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f94740048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f948c0687c0] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[0000564ce11580a0] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f948c06e460] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00007f948c06e460] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed for 128389: no reference clock
[00007f948c06e460] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 0 for spdif
[0000564ce11580a0] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f948c1c6c00] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00007f94740048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f94740048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f94740048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f94880015e0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 1000 ms)
[00007f94880015e0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 1162 ms)
[00007f94880015e0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 2083 ms)
[00007f94880015e0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (jitter of 7128 ms ignored)
[00007f94880015e0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 4814 ms)
[00007f94880015e0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (jitter of 21176 ms ignored)
[00007f94880015e0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 5954 ms)
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f948c0687c0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed for 15493623: no reference clock
[00007f948c0687c0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 0 for FFmpeg
[00007f948c1c6c00] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed for 15445623: no reference clock
[00007f948c1c6c00] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 0 for spdif
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f94740048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f94740048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f94740048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f948c06e460] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f94880015e0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (jitter of 14233 ms ignored)
[00007f948c003ec0] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f948c06e460] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[0000564ce11580a0] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f948c06e460] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[0000564ce11580a0] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f948c06e460] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[0000564ce11580a0] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f948c06e460] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00007f94740048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f94740048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f94740048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f94880015e0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (jitter of 8362 ms ignored)
[00007f94880015e0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (jitter of 6018 ms ignored)
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f947807e140] get_buffer() failed
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f947807e140] thread_get_buffer() failed
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f947807e140] get_buffer() failed (-12 (nil))
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
dave@ubuntustudio2019:~$ vlc
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[000055f657ac0580] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[000055f657b603d0] main playlist: playlist is empty
[00007f5cf4007680] dvdnav demux: DVD Title: HOBBIT_BATTLE_OF_FIVE_ARMIES
[00007f5cf4007680] dvdnav demux: DVD Serial Number: 46435A1D
[00007f5cf4007680] dvdnav demux: DVD Title (Alternative): HOBBIT_BATTLE_OF_FIVE_ARMIES
[00007f5cf4007680] dvdnav demux: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00e50000. Regions: 02 04 05
[00007f5cf4007680] dvdnav demux: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
[00007f5cf4007680] dvdnav demux: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient
[00007f5cf4007680] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f5cf4007680] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f5cf4007680] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f5ce40048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f5ce40048b0] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[00007f5ce40048b0] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[00007f5ce40048b0] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
[00007f5ce40048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f5ce40048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f5cf4069960] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[000055f657b90e70] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f5cf40682a0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[000055f657b90e70] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f5cf41ca330] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00007f5ce40048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f5ce40048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f5ce40048b0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
dave@ubuntustudio2019:~$ vlc
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[000056435ab1b580] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[000056435abbb3a0] main playlist: playlist is empty
[00007f112c001130] dvdnav demux: DVD Title: HOBBIT_BATTLE_OF_FIVE_ARMIES
[00007f112c001130] dvdnav demux: DVD Serial Number: 46435A1D
[00007f112c001130] dvdnav demux: DVD Title (Alternative): HOBBIT_BATTLE_OF_FIVE_ARMIES
[00007f112c001130] dvdnav demux: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00e50000. Regions: 02 04 05
[00007f112c001130] dvdnav demux: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
[00007f112c001130] dvdnav demux: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient
[00007f112c001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f112c001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f112c001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f111c004490] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f111c004490] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[00007f111c004490] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[00007f111c004490] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
[00007f111c004490] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f111c004490] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f112c063690] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[000056435abf31e0] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f112c1b16f0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[000056435abf31e0] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f112c1a84e0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00007f111c004490] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f111c004490] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f111c004490] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
dave@ubuntustudio2019:~$ vlc
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[000055b33fc5e580] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[000055b33fcfe3a0] main playlist: playlist is empty```
````

Answer (score 0):

I was able to stop the stuttering on affected dvds by going into:-

Preferences (Advanced) > Input/Codecs > Advanced

and increasing all the caching settings to:-
File caching (ms): 10000
Live capture: 3000
Disc caching: 10000      < I think this is probably the only one that matters
Network caching: 10000
Clock reference: 40
Clock synchronisation: Default
Clock jitter: 5000

It now takes noticeably longer for videos to load (around 10s, naturally).
Not all of the errors are resolved, indeed vlc isn't looking too happy, but the stuttering problem is gone and dvds play. I'll paste some of the current errors below:-

```
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[000055eac3cbf580] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[000055eac3d5f3a0] main playlist: playlist is empty
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: DVD Title: HOBBIT_BATTLE_OF_FIVE_ARMIES
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: DVD Serial Number: 46435A1D
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: DVD Title (Alternative): HOBBIT_BATTLE_OF_FIVE_ARMIES
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00e50000. Regions: 02 04 05
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f59f0004ba0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f59f0004ba0] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[00007f59f0004ba0] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[00007f59f0004ba0] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
[00007f59f0004ba0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f59f0004ba0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f59f4065320] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[000055eac3d971b0] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f59f41b11a0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[000055eac3d971b0] vlcpulse audio output error: digital pass-through stream connection failure: Device or resource busy
[000055eac3d971b0] main audio output error: module not functional
[00007f59f41b11a0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00007f59f41b11a0] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed for 128389: no reference clock
[00007f59f41b11a0] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 0 for FFmpeg
[000055eac3d971b0] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f59f404fc00] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[000055eac3d971b0] vlcpulse audio output error: digital pass-through stream connection failure: Device or resource busy
[000055eac3d971b0] main audio output error: module not functional
[00007f59f404fc00] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00007f59f0004ba0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f59f0004ba0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f59f0004ba0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f59f0004ba0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f59f0004ba0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f59f0004ba0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f59f41b11a0] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f5a040009a0] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 10000 ms)
[00007f59f4001130] dvdnav demux: Menu Languages available: �� 
[00007f59f41b11a0] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[000055eac3d971b0] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f59f41b11a0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[000055eac3d971b0] vlcpulse audio output error: digital pass-through stream connection failure: Device or resource busy
[000055eac3d971b0] main audio output error: module not functional
[00007f59f41b11a0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[000055eac3d971b0] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f59f41b11a0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[000055eac3d971b0] vlcpulse audio output error: digital pass-through stream connection failure: Device or resource busy
[000055eac3d971b0] main audio output error: module not functional
[00007f59f41b11a0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[000055eac3d971b0] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f59f41b11a0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[000055eac3d971b0] vlcpulse audio output error: digital pass-through stream connection failure: Device or resource busy
[000055eac3d971b0] main audio output error: module not functional
[00007f59f41b11a0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00007f59f0004ba0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f59f0004ba0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f59f0004ba0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
dave@ubuntustudio2019:~$ vlc
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[00005561349da580] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0000556134a7a3a0] main playlist: playlist is empty
```